# Automapper c# collection into objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mapping, automapper

I have an issue with c# mvc and automapper.
I have some models, this is one:

```
public class UserProfileModel
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public UserProfileModel()
    {
        this.Profili_Allocati = new List<Profili_AllocatiModel>();
        this.Tbl_SchedaValutativa = new List<Tbl_SchedaValutativaModel>();
    }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "This field should not exceed 150 characters")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    [StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "This field should not exceed 150 characters")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Cognome { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public int Specializzazione { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:mm/dd/yyyy}")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DataNascita { get; set; }
    [StringLength(256, ErrorMessage = "This field should not exceed 256 characters")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [StringLength(1, ErrorMessage = "This field should not exceed 1 characters")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "This field should not exceed 50 characters")]
    public string Telefono { get; set; }

    public CodeTableModel CodeTable { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public List<Profili_AllocatiModel> Profili_Allocati { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public List<Tbl_SchedaValutativaModel> Tbl_SchedaValutativa { get; set; }
}
```

And this code for mapping (from database):

```
  Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<CodeTable, CodeTableModel>()
            .ForMember(lc => lc.UserProfile, opt => opt.Ignore())
          .ForMember(lc => lc.Tbl_OpportunitaSkill, opt => opt.Ignore())
          .ForMember(lc => lc.CodeTableType, opt => opt.MapFrom(rc => rc.CodeTableType));
            cfg.CreateMap<Opportunita, OpportunitaModel>()
             .ForMember(lc => lc.Tbl_OpportunitaSkill, opt => opt.Ignore());
            cfg.CreateMap<CodeTableType, CodeTableTypeModel>();
            cfg.CreateMap<UserProfile, UserProfileModel>()
              .ForMember(lc => lc.Profili_Allocati, opt => opt.Ignore())
          .ForMember(lc => lc.Tbl_SchedaValutativa, opt => opt.Ignore())
          .ForMember(lc => lc.CodeTable, opt => opt.MapFrom(rc => rc.CodeTable));
            cfg.CreateMap<Tbl_OpportunitaSkill, Tbl_OpportunitaSkillModel>()
          .ForMember(lc => lc.Opportunita, opt => opt.MapFrom(rc => rc.Opportunita))
          .ForMember(lc => lc.CodeTable, opt => opt.MapFrom(rc => rc.CodeTable));
            cfg.CreateMap<Vw_OpportunitaSkill, Vw_OpportunitaSkillModel>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Vw_Opportunita, Vw_OpportunitaModel>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Vw_CheckProfile, Vw_CheckProfileModel>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Profili_Allocati, Profili_AllocatiModel>()
        .ForMember(lc => lc.UserProfile, opt => opt.MapFrom(rc => rc.UserProfile));

        });
```

When I try to go into Menus, I get an exception for unsupported mapping, how can I do?

Comment: What is "Menus"? I see no reference to anything like that in the posted code. In general, that exception occurs because some class involved in the mapping doesn't have a mapping configured for it. Usually, it's a relationship on one of the classes you *are* configuring mapping for. AutoMapper will walk all relationships by default, so every single class in the hierarchy will need a mapping, or you will need to explicitly ignore it in your mapping config.

Comment: menus are for views, where they call the models. thanks anyway